American mid-90s TV show, guy on the run in an RV
Someone will probably remember this. This was to my knowledge a short-lived show, perhaps one season only. A guy is on the run for some reason, he's moving around in an RV. Each episode saw him arriving in a new place, then there was an adventure there, and he moved on (I think there was a big picture story as well that was unfolded piece by piece). The guy had dark hair, and if I remember correctly, was usually wearing colorful shirts, Hawaiian shirts or something like that.
The lead character was about 25, lean physique. I was just a kid, I remember glimpses of the show not actual plots or settings.

Welcome to Movies & TV. Please try to add anything that may help identification. Are there any other plot details you remember or descriptions you can give?

I was just a kid, I remember glimpses of the show not actual plots or settings. The lead character was about 25, lean physique. The main thing is that he traveled around in that big RV, that should ring bells in anyone who watched it.

Feel free to [edit] any additional detail into the question.

I think you're after Johnny Bago, which aired for one season. From TVTropes:

Johnny Bago was a short-lived TV series airing on CBS in the summer of 1993, created by Robert Zemeckis and Jeffrey Price & Peter S. Seaman (Zemeckis also executive produced the series and directed the pilot) and starring Peter Dobson.
Small time hood Johnny Tenuti has just been released from prison after a five year sentence for a crime he claims not to have committed. His cousin, a mid-level Mafioso, asks Johnny to cover for him on a date which is on the same day as his wedding anniversary. Johnny does so, only to find himself framed for murdering the Mafia don's son.
So Johnny goes on the lam. He hooks up with an old man named Hick in a Winnebago RV. After Hick dies, Johnny repurposes Hick's RV and hides out in the RV community, travelling the highways and byways of America using the alias "Johnny Bago."

He was a young black-haired guy who occasionally wore gaudy shirts. Here's the intro:




The facts are a little vague so I'm going to take a stab at it.  This is possibly Promised Land, which was a spin-off of Touched By An Angel.  It ran from 1996 to 1999.  The RV was more like a trailer than a traditional RV, though, and the male lead was older than 25.  In fact, his whole family was with him.
